# Как правильно сформировать запрос в базу данных yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii

Есть три таблицы:

[image: Таблицы]

Каждому пользователю присвоены статусы, статусов у каждого может быть несколько, как мне получить пользователя, у которого, например, нет статуса под id = 1?

В данном случае это должен быть Петя

Сразу говорю, что такой метод не дает результатов:

```
$users = Users::find()
    ->joinWith('userStatuses')
    ->where(['not in', UserStatuses::tableName().'.status_id', [1]])
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо описать релейшены с таблицы users на user_statuses
1 к М
затем сделать простой запрос.

если с этим проблема, то в дебаггере просто посмотрите запросы на странице, найдите данный запрос и изучите на предмет что в нем не так